# Rails | SQL where date range but inclusive

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date

I have a date range as;

```
start_day = Date.parse("2017-02-15")
last_day = Date.parse("2017-02-17")
```

I would like to get records as;

```
@availabilities = Availabilities.where(date: start_day..last_day)
```

But the thing here is, it looks for the records in between. I need to check for `15` & `17` as well. Because when I use this, it returns nil. However, I have a record for `2017-02-15`.

Thank you.

Comment: If `Availabilities.where(date: start_day..last_day)`is exclusive, just do ```start_day = Date.parse("2017-02-15") - 1
    last_day = Date.parse("2017-02-17") + 1```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
@availabilities = Availabilities.where("date >= ? AND date <= ?",start_day,last_day)
```